# Matlab: How do I create multiple fields in a struct with a for loop

Tags: matlab

I need to create a bunch of fields in a struct with names that differ only by a digit, like this:

```
S(1).field1 = [];
S(1).field2 = [];
S(1).field3 = [];
S(1).field4 = [];
S(1).field5 = [];
```

This is a short version of the list. The real one is actually long and doesn't look pretty in the script so I am wondering whether I can initiate those empty fields within a for loop. I tried:

```
for i = 1:5
    S(1).field{i} = [];
end
```

but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use dynamic field names: this means that `S.field1` is *exactly the same as* `S.('field1')`. In action:

```
for k = 1:5
    S(1).(['field' num2str(k)]) = [];
end
```

Note that I changed the loop variable to `k`: `num2str(i)` could also return `0+1i` if you're not careful.

There are also some more funky, seemingly loopless solutions, such as:

```
n = 5;
S = cell2struct(cell(1,5),...
                arrayfun(@(x) ['field' num2str(x)],1:n,'uniformoutput',false),...
                2);
```

This will create a cell `{[],[],[],[],[]}` for the field values, and another cell `{'field1','field2',...,'field5'}` for the field names, and constructs a struct from these.